# is it legit to call an async function directly in react component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using indexeddb to store data, and use useReducer() to handle action.

but I'm not sure calling an async function directly in react component is correct.

thanks

```
function Component({ dispatch }) {
  function pushToast() {
    const id = uniqid();
    dispatch({ type: "PUSH_TOAST", payload: { id, content: "success" } });
    setTimeout(() => dispatch({ type: "CLEAR_TOAST", payload: { id } }) , 3000);
  }
  async function getDocs() {
    try {
      const result = await idb.getDocs();
      dispatch({ type: "REQUEST_SUCCESS", payload: result });
      pushToast();
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({ type: "REQUEST_FAIL" });
    }
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={getDocs}></button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. that's possible in react component but you can't do it inside a constructor, because constructor can't wait for await.

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly fine to use async functions for onClick inside a functional component.